# Background color different in listview and textview with margins

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have set this color:

```
<color name="lightgrey">#1a000000</color>
```

And have this `layout` with a `textview` that as margins and one `listview`.

As you can see in the below image, there's a slightly difference in the background color of the `texview`and the `listview`

[image]

**Why is this happening?**

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@color/lightgrey"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/queryTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal"
            />

    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:textFilterEnabled="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And `@drawable/rect`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/white"/>

<corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dip"
        android:topRightRadius="5dip"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the background colour into proper format like #e3e3e3 (max 6 chars) as android probably ignores the rest of the chars. Change the background color to a max 6 char color set and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Check the layout you use for the list items, maybe you are using a different background color to the background of the main layout.

... and remember add always the next attribute on the ListView Tag to avoid having a black background when scroll the list.

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" // setting transparent color
```

Comment: No. The layout I inflate for every row of my listview, as the exact same color. It's `@color/lightgrey`

Comment: Could you paste the layout you are using for the list items? Are you sure you're not changing the background color from source code?

Comment: the possible reason could be the color selection code, try another say #e3e3e3 and see what difference is there, because I don't think that more than 6 chars in color selection are valid, the rest are skipped automatically! give it a try or post your LIST xml code.

Comment: @Saqib That was probably the answer. Changed the color to `#bdbdbd` and it's working as it should. Please provide me the answer so I can mark it as the correct one